# Removing directories with spaces with bash

Tags: bash, find

I'm using the following command to remove every ".dummy" directories in a folder named "Test Folder":

```
rm -rf `find "Test Folder" -type d -name .dummy`
```

However, this doesn't work since it expands to, say:

```
rm -rf Test Folder/.dummy
```

Since the whitespace is not escaped, this fails.

I also tried something like this:

```
find "Test Folder" -type d -name .dummy -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

It works, but it gives an annoying error like this:

```
find: Test Folder/.dummy: No such file or directory
```

Is there a way to make either solution to succeed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A couple of things.  Easiest is to change and use

```
$ find 'Test Folder' -type d -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

Another choice is

```
$ find 'Test Folder' -type d -exec \'{}\' \;
```

Comment: add `-depth` to the `find` command or if you have `path/.dummy/path/.dummy` you will get errors.

Comment: Charlie, it seems your command will delete the whole "Test Folder" and not only its ".dummy/" subdir(s) (missing the `-name .dummy` )

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
find "Test Folder" -type d -name .dummy -exec rm -rf \"{}\" \;
```

Note the extra quotes in the `rm -rf "{}"` arg to the `-exec` option.  They're required because the name `Test Folder/.dummy` has a space in it.  So you need quotes.

Comment: Are the extra quotes actually needed? I wasn't sure they were.

Comment: you want to \ escape the quotes at the {} -- otherwise they're eaten by the shell command line parse.

Answer (score 2):

find "Test Folder" -type d -name '.dummy' -delete